# QGIS Welcome page: What is 'pin to list' for?

Tags: qgis-3

In QGIS 3 Welcome page when I right click a project a tiny context menu with 'pin to list' rsp. 'unpin from list' as first entry appears.

'pin to list' produces a little pin near the project name and 'unpin from list' removes the pin:

[image]

[image]

I consulted the documentation but I could not figure out the deeper sense of these pins.

Does somebody know what these pins are for? Perhaps some kind of favourite projects?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this feature. I never noticed it before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pin To List will add the project to the top of the Recent Projects list. This list appears when you start QGIS or in the menu Project > Open Recent. Your pinned projects will appear at the top of the list, allowing you to easily access them.